# Getting the Vertices numbers from an Edge

Tags: julia, lightgraphs

I am using the shortest path algorithm from LightGraphs.jl. In the end I want to collect some information about the nodes along the path. In order to do that I need to be able to extract the vertices from the edges that the function gives back.

```
Using LightGraphs
g = cycle_graph(4)
path = a_star(g, 1, 3)
edge1 = path[1]
```

Using this I get: `Edge 1 => 2`
How would I automatically get the vertices 1, 2 without having to look at the Edge manually? I thinking about some thing like `edge1[1]` or `edge1.From` which both does not work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accessors for `AbstractEdge` classes are [`src`](https://juliagraphs.org/LightGraphs.jl/stable/types/#LightGraphs.src-Tuple%7BAbstractEdge%7D) and [`dst`](https://juliagraphs.org/LightGraphs.jl/stable/types/#LightGraphs.dst-Tuple%7BAbstractEdge%7D), used like this:

```
using LightGraphs
g = cycle_graph(4)
path = a_star(g, 1, 3)
edge1 = path[1]

s = src(edge1)
d = dst(edge1)

println("source: $s")       # prints "source: 1"
println("destination: $d")  # prints "destination: 2"
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed!